# How to show that the normalized portfolio given by the Markowitz portfolio optimization model is efficient?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, markowitz

[image]
How can I show this? It looks relatively easy but am not sure if I am doing it right.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Well I was thinking of using the efficient frontier and show that all other portfolios will yield either a lower return or have higher risk. But I am not sure how to express it with the Markowitz model assumptions.